# How to make sure that Javascript object has every field defined when using index signatures?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```js
export interface Students {
  [studentName: string]: Exam[];
}

interface Exam {
  testName: string;
  testScore: number;
}

const studentsExample: Students = {
  john: [
    { testName: "Biology", testScore: 92 },
    { testName: "Math", testScore: 76 },
  ],
  sarah: [
    { testName: "English", testScore: 87 },
    { testName: "Economics", testScore: 95 }
  ]
};


const studentsExample2: Students = {
  john: [
    { testName: "Biology", testScore: 92 },
    { testName: "Math", testScore: 76 },
  ],
  sarah: [
    { testName: "English", testScore: 87 },
    { testName: "Economics"}
  ],
};
```

How do I make sure that every student in the students object has both the testName and testScore defined for every exam? In other words, how do I make sure a Students object is like studentExample and not studentExample2?

If the Students interface used regular fields, I would just do something like this:

```
for (const exam of students.firstStudent.exams) {
  if (exam.testName === undefined || exam.testScore === undefined) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

But with the index signature field, I don't know what all of the student names will be in advance, so how do I make sure that the students have testName and testScore for every exam?

Comment: Use `Object.keys`

Comment: Or `for (studentName in studentsExample) { // your code }`. Note how this uses "for ... **in**"  "for ... **of**".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do loop in entire object like

```
const students = {
  firstStudent: { exams: [] },
  secondStudent: { exams: [] }
};

for (const [studentName, value] of Object.entries(students)) {
  console.log(`${studentName}: ${value.exams.length}`);

}
```